# Authorization Framework for Java

Tags: java, security, authorization

I am searching for an authorization framework written if possible in Java that provides somewhat similar functionaility as AWS IAM.
Example:

- PRINCIPAL CAN/CANNOT do ACTION on RESOURCE

Where all of the params can be expressions like: Principal(*) CAN do (mail:*) on (/server/A/*)

I am having hard time finding anything because the search engine always return Spring Security and the likes - in which I am not interested.
I want to implement purely busness logic permissions and not any HTTP request related security etc.

The closest things I found are: Keycloak's Authz framework and [Cerbos](https://docs.cerbos.dev/cerbos/latest/glossary/index.html) (written in go

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe keycloak ? https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html

Comment: Hello @TacheDeChoco yes we are looking at keycloak but we had really bad experience when we tested Authz - it is not very mature. We wanted to implement authz inside our application thus the need to find some framework that is not tied to a whole software solution like keycloak

Comment: Spring security is not bound to HTTP requests. You can write expressions on any kind of `@Component` (including `@Service` or `@Repository`) using SpEL in `@PreAuthorize` and alike. Sample in this tutorial: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication